# laravel- how to generate pdf for invoice and purchase order?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a view page that returns all the info that the customer purchases for their orders. And as usual, an order comes with an invoice and purchase order where as a admin, I can click on the invoice of the order and it downloads the attachment (shown on bottom left of browser). The download file extension is based on what the invoice attachment is but I am wondering is there a simple and elegant way to make sure the file is in PDF format when I download it?

So let's assume the admin retrieve the invoices for the customer orders and populate the view. I assume I need to make sure the file path is in pdf format. I have the invoice template written in `blade.php` at the moment but not sure how to proceed from there.

Please advice.

Invoice:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Invoice</title>
 {{-- <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">  --}}
   
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
     
        <span class="float-left " > <img src="{{ asset('images/Logo.png') }}" style="width:60%;" alt="No Logo"></span>
       
       <div class="float-center">

        <h4>DC Signature Livingstyle SDN BHD</h4>
        <small> 1-21-01,Menara Bangkok Bank,Berjaya Central Park,No 105,Jalan Ampang,50450 Kuala Lumpur,Malaysia </small><br>
        <small>603-02818821 &emsp;  bujishu@gmail.com &emsp;   www.bujishu.com </small>

       </div>
       
        <div class="float-right">
        <strong>Invoice:[Invoice Number]</strong> 
        <br> 
        <strong>[Date Placeholder]</strong> <br>
        <strong>Credit Term:[Cash]</strong> 
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
      <div class="row mb-4">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
      <h6 class="mb-3">From:</h6>
      <div>
      <strong>[Panel Name]</strong>
      </div>
      <div>[Address 1]</div>
      <div>[Address 2]</div>
      <div>Email:[panel_email]</div>
      <div>Phone: [panel_number]</div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="col-sm-6">
      <h6 class="mb-3">To:</h6>
      <div>
      <strong>[Customer Name]</strong>
      </div>
      <div> [Shipping address 1] </div>
      <div>[shipping address 2]</div>
      <div>Email:[customer_email]</div>
      <div>Phone: [customer_number]</div>
      </div>
      
      
      
      </div>
      
      <div class="table-responsive-sm">
      <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
      <tr >
      <th class="center">No</th>
      <th>Item</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      
      <th class="left">Quantity</th>
        <th class="center">Unit Price (RM)</th>
      <th class="right">Amount(RM)</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <tr>
      <td class="center">1</td>
      <td class="left strong">Electrical wire</td>
      <td class="left">Longest wire ever</td>
      
      <td class="center">1</td>
        <td class="left">999,00</td>
      <td class="right">999,00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td class="center">2</td>
      <td class="left">Interior design</td>
      <td class="left">Instalation and Customization (cost per hour)</td>
      
      <td class="left">20</td>
        <td class="center">150</td>
      <td class="right">3.000,00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td class="center">3</td>
      <td class="left">Table</td>
      <td class="left">Round table</td>
      
      <td class="left">1</td>
        <td class="center">499,00</td>
      <td class="right">499,00</td>
      </tr>
   
      </tbody>
      </table>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
      
      
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-5 ml-auto " >
        <table class="table table-clear ">
        <th><strong> Payment Received </strong></th>
        <tbody>
          <tr style="page-break-after: always;">
            <td class="left">
              Payment Method: xxxxxx
            </td>       
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="left">
              Reference No: 2192012
            </td>       
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="left">
              Amount Paid: RM10,000.00 
            </td>       
          </tr>

          
          
          <tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      
    
      
      </div>
      
      </div>
      
      </div>

      <h6 style="margin-left:30%;">This invoice is computer generated,no signature is required.</h6>
      </div>
     
    </div>
  

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you may use a popular package named [dompdf](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf) to make your invoices in pdf  format

Comment: @Moshiur is this package for download and view on browser as well?

Comment: yes ofcourse see documentation

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1):

Use this library

https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf

For Browser view

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf.invoice', $data);
return $pdf->stream('invoice.pdf');
```

For downloading

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf.invoice', $data);
return $pdf->download('invoice.pdf');
```

Comment: But if my invoice template is in `invoice.blade.php`, how do I pass it to the pdf? Will it convert it?

Comment: yes this is the code PDF::loadView('invoice', $data); it takes the blade view

Comment: Hi, unfortunately it only works if my invoice is basic html. Once I added table and all into it, it will throw an error saying frame not found in cellmap. Is there any fix to this?

Comment: it only happens it you are missing any tag or your table structure is incomplete. easy way to check it is to return view(); and see. If still can't resolved share the code.

Comment: I recently just went through this process. In my case, it was easier to make a view specifically for the PDF. Some of the bootstrap classes were not getting properly rendered by DOMPDF but overall, this is the way to go.